# Creating a local environment from an existing GAE installation

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a website that is currently running under GAE... unfortunately, I, nor anyone on the team, does not have access the local environment that it was created from.... Is it possible to create a local environment or at least get a copy of the application files and database from an existing GAE installation?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're referring as local environment. Yes you can download the code if you have access to it https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/downloading-source-code

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the application source code, not the "local environment".

Ideally this source code would be on a version control system (ie GIT,SVN), Google cloud platform provides free GIT repositories for your projects so you might try looking there first. There's also a tool for both Java and python that allow you to download the source of a deployed version, provided you are authenticated as either the dev who uploaded it or a project owner. **EDIT**: as stated by Dan Cornilescu this feature can be disabled.

As for the database info there's plenty of tools available to "export" your GAE datastore info, just consider for your project that it might be easier to do the queries manually than actually implementing this tools.

Comment: An additional requirement for being able to download the app code is that the app wasn't configured to `Permanently prohibit code downloads` (in the App Engine -> Settings -> Application Settings on the developer console). The config reads: "Once this is set, no one, including yourself, will ever be able to download the code for this application using the appcfg download_app command."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help... But unfortunately, this code is not in GIT.  Furthermore, 
being new to Google hosting, I wasn't clear on my setup...  My web instance is actually running within Compute Engine not Application Engine.  Be that as it may, with some additional search, I was first able to find out how to browse my filesystem by accessing the VM Instances menu option under the Compute Engine section of the Google Cloud Platform interface.   On the VM Instances page, it will show your instance and an option to the left side of the instance to connect with a drop down box that will allow you to open a browser window that shows the instance's file system.  In addition to this, I found this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ssfE6ODpak  that shows how to configure Filezila FTP client to access your server instance - very helpful.   From there, I was able to download all of my site files from the var/www directory.  Now, onto extracting my data... Thanks again!